# How to create plots showing odds ratios and 95% CI

Tags: r

I have estimates of odds ratio with corresponding 95% CI of 8 factors. How can I create a vertical plot in R showing factors in the x axis and odds ratios and 95% CI in the y axis? This will be similar to forest plots except the factors will be presented in the x axis and number will be displayed in the y axis. 
Sample data to produce the figure is the following:

```
Factors       odds Ratios      UB      LB
A                 1.1         1.27    0.96
B                 1.63        2.46    1.08
C                 1.47        2.22    0.97
D                 0.98        1.16    0.82
E                 0.9         1.07    0.75
F                 0.76        0.92    0.63
G                 0.77        0.93    0.64
H                 0.98        1.15    0.83
```

Comment: You did a good job presenting data and clearly asking what you want, but I would strongly encourage you to show evidence of a little more research effort for your next question(s): this is pretty much "I want to do <X>, please give me the code".  Ideally you would show what you had already tried and where you got stuck/why it didn't work and people would help you fix it or make alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using ggplot, for example:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Factors,y=odds_Ratios)) + 
geom_point() + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=LB,ymax=UB,width=0.1))
```

[image]

Your data, I renamed the odds ratio column to odds_Ratios to make it easier for plotting:

```
structure(list(Factors = structure(1:8, .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), class = "factor"), odds_Ratios = c(1.1, 
1.63, 1.47, 0.98, 0.9, 0.76, 0.77, 0.98), UB = c(1.27, 2.46, 
2.22, 1.16, 1.07, 0.92, 0.93, 1.15), LB = c(0.96, 1.08, 0.97, 
0.82, 0.75, 0.63, 0.64, 0.83)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```